# about for loop in C/CPP

Tags: c++

i run this rode in vistual studio 2013,

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int j;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++);
        {
            cout << i << " " << j << "\t";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the result is

[image]

The same code in gcc/g++ are both ok,so what is the right run step of for loop?

Comment: trailing semi-colon: `for (j = 0; j <= i; j++);<-- here` so the inner loop doesn't execute as you expect

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the semicolon after `for (j = 0; j <= i; j++);`.